# how to find a partial sum that approximates ln 2 to one decimal-place accuracy

Tags: calculus

[Question from calculus 1 part b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJTOD.png)

The solution for part b the is
|ln2-Sn|<0.05
But why should getting |ln2−Sn|<0.05 be enough to guarantee that Sn approximates ln2 to one decimal-place accuracy

Example:what if we have ln2=0.693147
then take 0.644
is in the range of 0.05 error
but it cant approximate to one decimal-place accuracy *the first tenth*
because 0.644~0.6
and ln2~ 0.7
[image: question and full solution]

Comment: It's difficult to understand what your question is. One thing is certain: the solution uses the alternating series classical [majoration by the first neglected term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Approximating_sums)

Comment: Is your question "Why should getting $|\ln 2 - S_n| < 0.05$ be enough to guarantee that $S_n$ approximates $\ln 2$ to one decimal-place accuracy?"

Comment: Yes, this is my question

Comment: For what it's worth, upon reflection, my answer was hasty.  I did not think the matter through.  Therefore, I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in the image in your question is incorrect, for the reason you've stated. (For example, if it turned out that the true value of $\ln 2$ was $0.6500000000000000001$, you would need to decrease your error to much less than $0.05$ in order to be sure that you were correctly rounding it to one decimal place.)

In order to find $\ln 2$ to one decimal place, you need to find a lower bound and a upper bound which both round to *the same value*. Since even partial sums are lower bounds for $\ln 2$ and odd partial sums are upper bounds, this means you need to find an $n$ where $S_{2n}$ and $S_{2n+1}$ both give the same value when rounded to the nearest tenth.

Unfortunately there is no way to do this except by experimentation -- that is, you have to keep computing $S_n$ until you find two consecutive partial sums which give the same value when rounded to the nearest tenth.